# Search for string in an array

Tags: arrays, matlab, graph

I have the following code that construct a graph from a given matrix . 
The obtained graph has two type of nodes : type `O`  and type `S`.

```
B=[0 0 0 0;0 0 1 0;1 1 1 0;0 1 0 0;1 0 1 0;0 1 1 0;0 1 0 1;0 1 0 1;0 0 0 1; 0 0 0 1];   % Example Matrix
        disp('The Matrix of the system is the following');
        display(B);                                 % Get the system matrix 
        nNodeCol = size(B,2);                            % one node for each column of B
        nNodeLine = size(B,1)/2;                         % one node for every two lines of B
        % First the column nodes, then the line nodes:
        nodeNames = [cellstr(strcat('O',num2str((1:size(B,2))'))) ; cellstr(strcat('S',num2str((1:size(B,1)/2)')))];
     % Adjacency matrix adj, adj(i,j)=1 means there is an edge from node#i to node#j:
        adj = zeros(nNodeCol+nNodeLine);                 % square matrix which size is the number of nodes
        adj(1:nNodeCol, nNodeCol+1:end) = B(1:2:end,:)'; % edge from a column node to a line node is added for all the 1 in the first line of the node in the matrix
        adj(nNodeCol+1:end, 1:nNodeCol) = B(2:2:end,:);  % edge from the line node to a column node is added for all the 1 in the second line of the node in the matrix
        % Creation of the graph:
        G = digraph(adj,nodeNames);
        for x=1: nNodeCol
            v{x} = dfsearch(G,nodeNames{x});     % Finding paths from nodes type O .
        end
        celldisp(v);
```

Now, we have the array `v` in which every cell contains the set of nodes that are results of dfsearch on nodes of type `O`  ( so `v{1}` contains results of `dfsearch(G,O1)`, and so go on ..), i got the following results :

```
v{1}= (O1,S2,O2,S4,S5,S3,O3)
v{2}= (O2,S2,S4,S5)
v{3}= (O3,S2,O2,S4,O4,S5,S3)
v{4}= (O4,S4,O2,S2,S5)
```

Now, my problem is the following : I want to get another array `W` that have the size `nNodeLine`  which is the number of nodes of type `S` and every `W{x}` contains the first element of `v{x}` `(v{x}{1})` and in which `Sx` is part of `v{x}`. For exemple `w{1}` will containt all the first elements of `v{x}` where `S1` is included. So i must get the following :

```
W{1}= {}
W{2}= {O1,O2,O3,O4}
W{3}= {O1,O3}
W{4}= {O1,O2,O3,O4}
W{5}= {O1,O2,O3,O4}
```

Any suggestions ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check this,

```
for i=1:5
    ss=['S',int2str(i)];
    k=0;
    for j=1:4
        if  not(isempty(find(strcmp(v{1,j,:},ss))))
            w{1,i}{k+1,1}=v{1,j}{1,1};
        end
        k=k+1;
    end
    if  isempty(w{1,i})
        w{1,i}={};
    end
end
```

It has small bug, I am currently busy to fix it, try to solve it yourself. If you can not, tell me in the comment I will fix it when I have time.

Comment: @Hazem......I don't see any bug ....if there is one can you fix it ....thank's for your answer .

Comment: Also what is the point of `ind=find(strcmp(v{1,j,:},ss));` since it hasn't been used ?